# Codeigniter sorting array

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting

I am using codeigniter directory_map function like this

```
$pdf = directory_map('./pages/'.lang('page_lang').'/pdf/spisak/');
sort($pdf);
foreach($pdf as $singlepdf) {
    echo '<li>
          <a target="_blank" href="pages/'.lang('page_lang').'/pdf/spisak/'.$singlepdf.'">'.substr($singlepdf, 0, -7).'</a>
          </li>';
}
```

The problem is have, is that I am sorting that file array, only problem is with serbian letters, like eastern european (Ђ,Д,Ш,Н etc.)
It does not sort them properly, it goes something like this

```
ЂУРИЧИЋ НЕБОЈША
АЂАНЋИЋ ДУШАН
```

But it should be like this

```
АЂАНЋИЋ ДУШАН
ЂУРИЧИЋ НЕБОЈША
```

Is there a way to properly sort eastern european array in codeigniter?

**EDITED**

I also in array have **ALEKSANDAR, BUDIMIR, АЛЕКСАНДАР**

After sorting i got something like this

```
ALEKSANDAR
BUDIMIR
АЛЕКСАНДАР
```

but i need somthing like this

```
ALEKSANDAR
АЛЕКСАНДАР
BUDIMIR
```

Comment: Ok, but this is custom, is there some codeigniter function for this?